# sending SMS via a commercial API (trendoo) : nullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sms

I ask for help because I have a nullpointerexception that I don't understand.

here is the code:

```
try {
            sr = application.launcher.getSmstrend().getConnexion()
                    .sendSMS(this);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        launcher.append(launcher.format_log.format(new Date())
                + " RDV.envoi : ERREUR d'envoi du message, " + e);
    }
```

to be noted : the getConnexion() method returns a valid object (not null), and the this parameter is also not null. Smstrend is not "trendoo", a site which sends SMS via a java API. The error is :

```
sam. 11 janv. 2014 22-08-54 RDV.envoi : ERREUR d'envoi du message, java.lang.NullPointerException
```

can you explain me where to search?where is the null reference?

Comment: it's unclear from what you've provided.  Try debugging and see where it comes from.

Comment: problem solved : the trendoo API specifies the message sender's name should not exceed 11 characters, and mine was 15 characters long. Reducing its length solved the error.